# How can I use GCP project from environment variable in gcp_compute dynamic inventory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, ansible-inventory

For my ansible playbooks I use dynamic invenotory [gcp_compute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html). But I don't want define projectID and region in this file, I want read it from environment variables.

In ansible-playbook I can use `lookup('env', 'FOO_BAR')`, and it works. But in invetory - do not.

[This guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html) says, that is possible to use some variables. I tryed it - it works, but there are not variables for project and region. (I also tryed use somethink like `GCP_PROJECT` or `GCP_PROJECT_ID`, but this is not work).